# I want to add date range where value is True in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, concatenation

| Dt | 1/2/21 | 2/2/21 | 3/2/21 | 4/2/21 | 5/2/21 | 6/2/21 | 7/2/21 | Attendance(Expected output in python) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| san | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | 1/2/21 - 7/2/21 |
| don | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | 1/2/21 -2/2/21,4/2/21-7/2/21 |
| sam | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | 2/2/21 - 3/2/21,5/2/21-7/2/21 |
| den | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | 3/2/21,5/2/21 - 6/2/21 |

I want to add Attendance column using pandas

Comment: `:TRUE` and `:TRUE:` are real values in your data or are they typos? If they're like that in the original dataset, you may want to strip the " : " from them before doing anything else.

Comment: I didn't perceive my comment as hostile, but I'll trust your point of view @ArchAngelPwn. I'll change my comment now.

Comment: Thanks boss! Its entirely possible its just the way I read it, but its my biggest pet peeve how absolutely RUDE people can be on this website (not saying you just in general) So its also absolutely possible I'm just a little overly sensitive haha

Comment: Wellcome to StackOverflow! Please, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/tour. Normally, we expect questions to elaborate a bit in what you have tried, and to be specific at describing the problem. For example, how the output you achieve differs in what you expected. Or if you couldn't achieve any output at all! Of course, "I have not idea where to start" can work, but don't expect people to write whole programs for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm starting from a previous answer to get a list of dates in the column "Attendance".

```
df['Attendance'] = [df.columns[(df.iloc[i] == True)].tolist()) for i in range(len(df.Dt)]
```

Now, I use pandas deltas (differences in time) to find consecutive days, extract only the first and last ones of each range of consecutives, and print it with the right format:

```
def get_consecutives(dates):
    consecutives = []
    delta_1day = pd.Timedelta('1d')    
    while len(dates) > 1:
        if dates[1] - dates[0] == delta_1day:
            consecutives.append(dates.pop(0))
        else:
            break
    consecutives.append(dates.pop(0))
    return consecutives

def all_days(dates):
  total = []
  while dates:
      total.append(get_consecutives(dates))

  formatted_total = ', '.join(['-'.join((range[0].strftime('%d/%m/%y'), range[-1].strftime('%d/%m/%y'))) if len(range) > 1 
                              else range[0].strftime('%d/%m/%y') for range in total])
  return formatted_total
```

Finally, I'll make a function to map all the previous to the "Attendance" column:

```
def mapping(list_of_dates):
    dates = pd.to_datetime(list_of_dates, dayfirst=True,).to_list()
    return all_days(dates)

df['Attendance'] = df['Attendance'].map(mapping)
```

Comment: While reading excel file ,date row is reading with time.So not able to fetch extract only the first and last ones of each range of consecutives .I tried using datetime converter but as this is header it not applying on header

Comment: I think because of datetime ,when  I used above code i got an error "delta_1day is not defined"

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. When I pasted the code, forgot one line. I added it now inside the get_consecutives function. Should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome and thank you for this nice "exercice"! ;)

This is the best I can do.

I iterate through each rows with list comprehension using `.iloc[]`, and check which `.columns` is/are `True`, then a `''.join()` the result, make them a list with `.tolist()` to be able to assign to the new column.

```
df['Attendance'] = [','.join(df.columns[(df.iloc[i] == True)].tolist()) for i in range(len(df.Dt))]
df
```

| index | Dt | 1/2/21 | 2/2/21 | 3/2/21 | 4/2/21 | 5/2/21 | 6/2/21 | 7/2/21 | Attendance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | san | true | true | true | true | true | true | true | 1/2/21,2/2/21,3/2/21,4/2/21,5/2/21,6/2/21,7/2/21 |
| 1 | don | true | true | false | true | true | true | true | 1/2/21,2/2/21,4/2/21,5/2/21,6/2/21,7/2/21 |
| 2 | sam | false | true | true | false | true | true | true | 2/2/21,3/2/21,5/2/21,6/2/21,7/2/21 |
| 3 | den | false | false | true | false | true | true | false | 3/2/21,5/2/21,6/2/21 |